# gdb: The program 'x' has exited with code 177. How to find out which lib is responsible?

Tags: debugging, gdb, cross-compiling

I am working in VSCode with WSL(ubuntu) (x64 host) and cross-compile for arm64 (raspberry pi).
If a section of the code is commented out it is possible to debug on the target, but if the section (obiously using some shared libs) is commented in again the gdb debbuger does not even start.
All i have is this :

[image]

so my question is, is there any way to make gdb more verbose to tell me why it exits with error 177?
From searching the web I already found out that it has to be related to shared libs which gdb can not load.
So is there any way to make gdb more verbose to tell me which lib?